# what does " models.Model "mean

Tags: python, django

I'm working through https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/ . 
They include the following :

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

what does " models.Model "mean?

Comment: inheritance. Do you have any programming experience even in another language??? Like C# E.g.:
public class A
{
    public A() { }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B() { }
}

Class B inherits A... This is basic OOP, but without knowing your background it is hard to explain better...

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I should have been more specific. I'm coming from php where I have used some OOP techniques

Comment: Think about:

class bar extends foo
{
    public function printItem($string)
    {
        echo 'Bar: ' . $string . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

I will expand my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For answer this question you need to know the meaning of module, package and class in python.
In summary a **module** is basically a collection of related code stored in a file with a `.py` extension. You can define functions, classes or variables in a module.
To use the module in the main program, follow the code below:

```
import My_Module
```

When developing a large application, you may encounter various modules that are difficult to manage. In this case, you will benefit from grouping and organizing your modules. That's when **packages** come into play.
This image is a example for package in python:

[image]

To be considered a package, a directory must contain a file named **init**.py .
We can import specific **modules** from this package using the dot symbol. For example, we can use this code to import the **dataset** module from the above package:

```
from my_model.training import dataset
```

With these definitions, you now understand **models** is one of the Django modules which includes functions and classes And the **Model** is a class that **models** use it for working with database, and your poll class inherited from each other .

Answer (score 8):

It means: make the `Poll` class inherit from the `Model` base class from the `models` module.

Comment: Is the models module part of Django or a python construct?

Comment: It's a Django module, as you can see from `from django.db import models`

Answer (score 6):

Do you know what inheritance is? I would start by looking at some examples:

http://parand.com/say/index.php/2009/04/20/python-simple-inheritance-example/

It is basically saying to use all the properties that the Model class has plus whatever you define on your class.

Good luck

---

in php that would be:

```
class Poll extends Model
{
    var $question;
    var $pub_date;
}
```

Model is a class that is in the models module in Django framework...

Answer (score 0):

It's the class that you are sub-classing to create your model.